# Codename one Why are events disabled?

Tags: codenameone

Please what do I have to do?

In codename one in the codename one designer events are disabled, how do I solve this....?
I see the messages but its not clear to me....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide additional information on what it is that you did. In general that happens if the resource file isn't within the src directory of the project or if you removed the project properties in the root of the project.